# Insert Image with PostDeployment script with Visual Studio Database Project

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, software-design, database-project

I have a visual studio sql server database project, and an Images table. I need insert a default image in a PostDeployment script, because this image will be used in all entities with an empty image. How can I store this image in the project, and how can access it in the script?

Insert this image in the database project is a good practice? I have a WindowsService project, and a ASP.NET MVC project with entity framework. Should I insert this image in some kind of initial verification in each one of this other 2 projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

Given a table

```
create table testImage
(id int,
myImage varbinary( max));
```

You can insert an image from a file with something like:

```
INSERT INTO testImage (id, myImage)
SELECT 1, bulkcolumn
FROM openrowset(BULK 'D:\x\dZLx1.png', single_blob) as myImage
```

There are a couple of potential headaches here, you need to keep track of the path to the image in your project somehow, and I think there are a few security-related scenarios where `OPENROWSET` doesn't work anyway.

It might be more reliable to do this once on your desktop, then `SELECT` the value out again to use in an insert statement such as

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM testIMAGE where ID = 2)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO testImage VALUES
(2,0x89504E470D0A1A0.....)
END
```

(full script here: https://gist.github.com/gavincampbell/a25431dffd3555563a052c297a32415e)

As you will realise when you try this, the resulting string will be *long*. I think it would be a good idea to keep this in a separate script and reference it from the main post-deploy script with `:r` (apologies if you knew this already!). Also remember that you don't need quotes around the binary "string".